# qt code to json transformation

Tags: java, json, qt

i have lot of qt that i  want to transform  to Json code 
this codes mostly like :

```
ApplicationWindow {
title: qsTr("Hello World")
width: 640
height: 480

menuBar: MenuBar {
    Menu {
        title: qsTr("File")
        MenuItem {
            text: qsTr("&Open")
            onTriggered: console.log("Open action triggered");
        }
        MenuItem {
            text: qsTr("Exit")
            onTriggered: Qt.quit();
        }
    }
}

Button {
    text: qsTr("Hello World")
    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
    anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
}}
```

this code is User interface code i want to transform it to Json code i try artistically coding way but i don't have a good result, there is a library in java or websites to do this?

Comment: You want to translate QML to JSON? Why? What would that achieve?

Comment: it s the better way to translate after Json to XML

Comment: Huh? What are you trying to do?

Comment: qml code to xml using json

Comment: And the point of doing that would be what, exactly?  What are you trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 0):

The manual translation is mostly straight-forward:

```
{
    "title": "Hello World",
    "width": 640,
    "height": 480,

    "menuBar": {
        "Menu": {
            "title": "File",
            "MenuItem": [{
                "text": "&Open",
                "onTriggered": "Open action triggered" <=== Possibly some further structure here
            },
            {
                "text": "Exit",
                "onTriggered": ???? <=== Not clear what should be here
            }
        }
    },

    "Button": {
        "text": "Hello World",
        ===> "anchors" could be a single JSON object with two elements <===
        "anchors.horizontalCenter": "parent.horizontalCenter" <=== Use numeric or character constant
        "anchors.verticalCenter": "parent.verticalCenter" <=== Ditto
    }
}
```

Note that type information is lost -- that needs to be either inferred or included explicitly.

Comment: sure if we use this code one time but i want to use it for millions transformations